# ACPI BIOS Errors on Debian (Not Present on Other Distros)

Tags: linux, debian

I'm encountering ACPI BIOS errors specifically on Debian-based distributions that are not present when using Pop!_OS, Fedora, or Arch-based distros. The errors occur consistently during every reboot.

**Errors:**

- 0.111517] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_SB.PCOO.IZCO.T01, AE_NOT_FOUND (20220331/dswload2-162)
- 0.1115241 ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20220331/psject-220)
- 0.111544] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_SB.PCOO.IZCO.T-11, AE_NOT_FOUND (20220331/dswload2-162)
- 0.111547] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20220331/psject-220)
- 0.1119131 ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_SB.PCIO], AE_NOT_FOUND (20220331/dswload2-162)
- 0.1119161 ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20220331/ps

I'd appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve these errors. Please let me know if you require further system information or error logs.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

**Additional Information:**

- Desktop model: [Lenovo IdeaPad gaming 3] i5 11th gen nvidia GTX 1650

Comment: do they prevent the system from functioning?

Comment: Are the kernel.printk variables the same in all distros? If they aren't, that may explain differing log levels. Check /proc/sys/kernel/printk, and /etc/sysctl.conf.